# MongoDb is not connecting in Cakephp

Tags: mongodb, cakephp-2.0

I am new to Cakephp & MongoDb. I am working on Ubuntu in which localhost is already set up and working correctly.I have made a new install of cakephp and changed config/database.php according to mongodb tutorials.

I have copied MongoDb and DebugKit from another working installtion to my working CakePhp folder.

But it's not working and showing warning messages.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually i didn't include the `CakePlugin::load('Mongodb');` in `cakefolder/lib/cake/bootstrap.php` .

Now it is working like charm.
I hope it will help someone.

Thanks.